# Apple Watch: Fastest way to adjust volume of iPhone

Tags: iphone, shortcut, apple-watch, sound-volume, watchos

Using the Apple Watch, what is the *fastest* way to adjust the volume of the iPhone?

Two assumptions/criteria:

- When you raise your wrist, the view on the Apple Watch from your wrist, should be the watch face view; not the last view used.
- Audio playing on the iPhone is coming from  *any* iOS app; not just Apple's *Music* app.

The fastest way I currently know of (by my expectations neither fast nor nimble) is to open the Dock by pressing the Dock button; navigate to the "Now Playing" view with the Digital Crown (having ordered that view near the bottom of the Dock list); and when the "Now Playing" view is active adjust the volume with the Digital Crown.

Unfortunately, "Now Playing" is not a proper watchOS application, and therefore cannot be brought up by double-pressing the Digital Crown, assuming it would've been the last app used.

I'm wondering if there is a quick way to adjust iPhone volume from the Apple Watch, using a keypress combination or something else.

I guess one option could be to tell Siri to *"lower volume by 10 %"*, but I find Siri control quite tedious, and it will interrupt current playback. Issuing a percentage change is ironically also a very discrete action, because it cannot be fine-tuned without having to issue a new voice command.

Comment: Er, in my experience Now Playing, if it is the most recently active app, _can_ be brought up by double-clicking the crown... Regardless, have you considered adding it as a complication? That would make three steps for volume adjustment: wake watch, tap complication, turn digital crown.

Comment: @Merlin Have you really tried double-tapping the Crown? Because it doesn't work for me for Now Playing. Furthermore, there's no Complication for it.

Comment: Ah, there's the problem: I almost never play media on my iPhone other than through the Music app, so I conflated Now Playing with Music's currently-playing view (which is pulled up by default through the Music complication or Crown double-click.) You are correct, my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: "Now Playing" app icon]

You said:

> Unfortunately, "Now Playing" is not a proper watchOS application

On the contrary, *Now Playing* is indeed an app on the Apple Watch. At least it is now in [watchOS 9.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WatchOS#watchOS_9). See the app icon above, a striped red triangle on a white background.

When streaming audio on apps such as CNBC or Bloomberg,  **I find the *Now Playing* app is always showing** on the Watch when I raise my wrist.

The only exception is if I am recording my “Workout”, “Outdoor Walk”. And even then I can swipe to the left to see *Now Playing*.

If I bring another app to the front, I can easily return to *Now Playing*: Press the side button to see the *Dock* showing recently used apps. That list of apps includes *Now Playing*.

When the *Now Playing* app is displayed, spin the crown to raise or lower the volume on the iPhone. In the first moment, the volume indicator in *Now Playing* may be grey before turning green. Apparently this split-second delay of grey-to-green is the Watch making contact with the iPhone. Almost an annoyance, but the delay is actually less than a second.

I am happy to report on this feature, as the sole reason for my purchase of an [Apple Watch SE (2022)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Watch#Eighth_generation_(Series_8,_SE_(2nd_gen)_&_Ultra)) was to adjust the volume of streaming audio while walking the dog. Turns out **this remote control for volume does indeed work well**, mission accomplished. Happy Bonus: I discovered the Apple Watch is *so* much more useful than just that.

Comment: When the question was asked over 5 years ago, "Now Playing" wasn't a stand-alone app in my recollection, and therefore it wasn't included in the Dock. Adjusting the volume of the iPhone via the Apple Watch was a more convoluted thing then.